# django's template tags and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, django

I have a small puzzle, I have in Django's template a following line of code:

```
{% if x == y %} sth {% endif %}
```

Where "x" variable belongs to Django while "y" is a angularjs variable. I've learned that one can change the $interpolateProvider to {$ $} or sth else, but in this case that's not an option since the code should than look like:

```
{% if x == {$ y $} %} sth {% endif %}
```

and that of course will cause an error. How to resolve that issue, i.e. to use angularjs variables inside the template tags?

I would be grateful for a tip,

best wishes,

nykon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I think the best solution is NOT to mix Django template language with angular. If you really need to depend on a django-provided variable, then you should pass it to the template, store it in a JS variable with something like:

```
var myVariable = {{ django_provided_var }};
```

Inside a `<script>` tag, and then use angular to do the display logic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this solution fits for you, but one option I've used some times is JavaScript, I passed Django & AngularJS to JavaScript and do the conditionals and actions there.

Something like:

```
<script>
var angular_variable = {$ y $}
var django_variable = {{x}}
// Depending on your example you may need to enclose the variables with ' '
var angular_variable = '{$ y $}'
var django_variable = '{{x}}'

if (anguar_variable == django_variable){
   // Do whatever you need to do
}

</script>
```